# Difficulty testing asynchronous function

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to learn Mocha and am having trouble dealing with asynchronous code.

I would like to create a test database, populate it with some data, and then write some tests. My issue is that I can not figure out how to require that my test database be created and populated before additional tests are run. Here's the basic structure of my code:

```
describe('Database', function() {

  // create the DB and populate it with some test data
  iniDB(dbName, function(db) {
    addDataToDB(db, table, data);
  });


  // tests below here

});
```

From reading the documentation, it seems that I need to use `before` to ensure that my asynchronous code runs prior to my tests. To attempt this, I tried using something like this:

```
describe('Database', function() {

  before(function(done) {
    iniDB(dbName, function(db) {
      addDataToDB(db, table, data);
    });
    done();
  });

  // tests below here

});
```

How can I tell Mocha to first create and populate my database before running subsequent tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `before()` is the right solution, just invoke `done()` when all your data has finished writing. Something like this:

```
before(function(done) {
  iniDB(dbName, function(db) {
    addDataToDB(db, table, data, function() {
      done();
    });
  });
});
```